# Manually match an url against the registered endpoints in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For my application I would like to match an url against all the registered routes to see there is a match.

When there is a match, I would like to extract the routevalues from the match.

I got this working in ASP.NET Core 2.1, but i do not seem to be able to retrieve the routes the way they are retrieved in .NET Core 3

Working ASP.NET Core 2.1 sample:

```
string url = "https://localhost/Area/Controller/Action";

// Try to match against the default route (but can be any other route)
Route defaultRoute = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Routers.OfType<Route>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Default");

RouteTemplate defaultTemplate = defaultRoute.ParsedTemplate;
var defaultMatcher = new TemplateMatcher(defaultTemplate, defaultRoute.Defaults);
var defaultRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
string defaultLocalPath = new Uri(url).LocalPath;

if (!defaultMatcher.TryMatch(defaultLocalPath, defaultRouteValues))
{
    return null;
}

string area = defaultRouteValues["area"]?.ToString();
string controller = defaultRouteValues["controller"]?.ToString(); 
string actiondefaultRouteValues["action"]?.ToString();
```

Is there a way to obtain all registered endpoints (templates) and match against these templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 2.1 and below, routing was handled by implementing the `IRouter` interface to map incoming URLs to handlers. Rather than implementing the interface directly, you would typically rely on the `MvcMiddleware` implementation added to the end of your middleware pipeline.

In ASP.NET Core 3.0, we use endpoint routing, so the routing step is separate from the invocation of the endpoint. In practical terms that means we have two pieces of middleware:

- `EndpointRoutingMiddleware` that does the actual routing i.e.
  calculating which endpoint will be invoked for a given request URL
  path.
- `EndpointMiddleware` that invokes the endpoint.

So you could try the following method to match an url against all the registered routes to see there is a match in asp.net core 3.0.

```
    public class TestController : Controller
  {
    private readonly EndpointDataSource _endpointDataSource;

    public TestController ( EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource)
    {
        _endpointDataSource = endpointDataSource;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string url = "https://localhost/User/Account/Logout";

        // Return a collection of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint instances.
        var routeEndpoints = _endpointDataSource?.Endpoints.Cast<RouteEndpoint>();
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        string LocalPath = new Uri(url).LocalPath;

        //To get the matchedEndpoint of the provide url
        var matchedEndpoint = routeEndpoints.Where(e => new TemplateMatcher(
                                                                    TemplateParser.Parse(e.RoutePattern.RawText),
                                                                    new RouteValueDictionary())
                                                            .TryMatch(LocalPath, routeValues))
                                            .OrderBy(c => c.Order)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (matchedEndpoint != null)
        {
            string area = routeValues["area"]?.ToString();
            string controller = routeValues["controller"]?.ToString();
            string action = routeValues["action"]?.ToString();
        }
        return View();
    }
   }
```

You could refer to [this blog](https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-terminal-middleware-to-endpoint-routing-in-aspnetcore-3/) for more details on the endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0.

Comment: This methods can lead to surprising results. Readers should loop over the results before using (or not) this condensed query. Briefly, 1) ordering should be done before the `where`, else, well, you get a random result unrelated with the `foundValues`. 2) the `routeValues` object is not re-initialized, so if two routes have different numbers of arguments, results from one transpire to the other. 3) even if you keep the "best" match, the `tryMatch` would have overwitten the values with the next attempt.

Comment: 4) Even if it uses all endpoints, the returned endpoint could (will) be an unexpected one: for example, if all routes use the default pattern `{controller}/{action}/{id?}`, then the pattern of the 1st endpoint will match any URL, so `abc/xyz` if found to match the pattern of endpoint for controller `foo` action `bar`
5) this fails with explicit routes, like `translated_controller/translated_action/{id}` pointing to a given controller/action, as it will match the pattern as if `translated_controller` was indeed the real controller name (and same for the action)

Comment: @JGH, do you have a working solution for this? Especially #4 makes this solution totally unusable.

Comment: @cooper_milton you can loop through the found endpoints and compare the controller/action from route values with a list of the possible controller/action