# Get Endpoint for different HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write a controller action that will get me metadata (specifically, which arguments to pass) for a given URL. There are a number of similar questions, such as [Asp.Net core get RouteData value from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505184/asp-net-core-get-routedata-value-from-url), but those don't seem to be correct as of ASP.NET Core 3.1, because it has switched to "Endpoint Routing".

As such, code like `var router = RouteData.Routers.First(); //get the top level router` will no longer work correctly, as `Routers` isn't filled with anything meaningful.

I see a few examples of using endpoints for the *current* HttpContext, such as [here](https://aregcode.com/blog/2019/dotnetcore-understanding-aspnet-endpoint-routing/), but none for a custom one.

I've also seen mention of `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`, but that won't let me easily filter for a particular URL.

So far, I'm injecting a HttpContextFactory, but passing it the `IEndpointFeature` from the current context:

```
    private readonly IHttpContextFactory _HttpContextFactory;

    public MyController(IHttpContextFact httpContextFactory)
    {
        _HttpContextFactory = httpContextFactory;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> GetRouteDataForUrl([FromQuery(Name = "url")] string url)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);

        // this is probably wrong -- it supplies the _original_ context's endpoint feature
        var featureCollection = this.HttpContext.Features;

        var httpContext = _HttpContextFactory.Create(featureCollection);
        httpContext.Request.Path = uri.PathAndQuery;

        var feature = httpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>();
        var endpoint = httpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint; // see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5135#issuecomment-461547335

        return Ok(endpoint.Metadata.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor>());
    }
```

This works to get me the correct types, but not the right results.

There's no public constructor for `EndpointFeature`, so I'm probably not supposed to pass my own. The above code takes the `IEndpointFeature` from the original ("wrong") http context, and as a result will give me an endpoint for the `GetRouteDataForUrl` controller, *not* for the controller I'm passing in the URL.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550580/9080566

Comment: Yeah, thanks! `EndpointDataSource` was also (part of) how I ultimately solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this (though I'm not sure I did so in the cleanest or most efficient manneR).

The two key pieces I ended up using are an `EndpointDataSource` and a `LinkParser`:

```cs
private readonly EndpointDataSource _EndpointDataSource;
private readonly LinkParser _LinkParser;

public MyController(EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource, LinkParser linkParser)
{
   _EndpointDataSource = endpointDataSource;
   _LinkParser = linkParser;
}
```

I can use the endpoint data source to iterate over *all* endpoints, and the link parser to match an end point against `expectedUri` (which is the URL passed by the user):

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetActionMetadata(Uri forUri)
{
    foreach (var endpoint in this._EndpointDataSource.Endpoints)
    {
        if (!TryGetEndpointMetadata(endpoint, out var name, out var controllerActionDescriptor))
            continue;

        // we only use this to match the endpoint to the URL
        var dict = _LinkParser.ParsePathByEndpointName(name, expectedUri.AbsolutePath);
        if (dict == null)
            continue;

        // if we get here, it's the endpoint we're looking for, and we can proceed with your actual parsing

         /* actually do things with the endpoint */
    }
}
```