# How can I find an endpoint from a url?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using Endpoint Routing and I'd like to find the correct Endpoint object for a given url and possibly request method. If I can at least find the Endpoint based on the url that would be helpful. Essentially I'm looking to implement the following method.

```
public Endpoint GetEndpoint(HttpContext httpContext, string url, string requestMethod)
{
    // I can get all of the endpoints
    var endpointDataSource = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<EndpointDataSource>();
    var endpoints = endpointDataSource.Endpoints;

    // But I'm not sure what to do here
}
```

I thought that maybe I could use the [DefaultLinkParser.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/127bc7ddd3617e765cf53571791c091288dc2ad5/src/Http/Routing/src/DefaultLinkParser.cs) but up to this point I've not figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way but this seems to work

```
public Endpoint GetEndpoint(HttpContext httpContext, string url, string requestMethod)
{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
    var endpointDataSource = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<EndpointDataSource>();
    var endpoints = endpointDataSource.Endpoints.OfType<RouteEndpoint>();

    foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
    {
        var templateMatcher = new TemplateMatcher(TemplateParser.Parse(endpoint.RoutePattern.RawText), new RouteValueDictionary());
        if (!templateMatcher.TryMatch(url, routeValues)) continue;
        var httpMethodAttribute = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<HttpMethodAttribute>();
        if (httpMethodAttribute != null && !httpMethodAttribute.HttpMethods.Any(x => x.Equals(requestMethod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) continue;
        return endpoint;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I got some ideas from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550580/384853